# HTML: Inputting a string in text box on Submit button not working

Tags: php, html

I'm facing a strange problem. I have a HTML form in which user can input the ID number and then submit the form to get the analysis. The problem that I'm facing is that when the user manually inputs the ID, the form doesn't submit, but if the ID is copy pasted in the Text box, and the click the submit button, it works and loads the analysis. Can someone please help.

the form looks like below:

```
    <form action="" method = "GET" class="form-inline">
            <div class="input-group" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;" >
                <span class="input-group-addon">Campaign IDs</span>
                <input type="text" name="campaigns" id="campaigns" style="width:220px;" value="<?=$campaigns?>" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
            </div>
        <input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' id='idsub'>
        </form>
```

and php is handled like this:

```
if(isset($_GET["campaigns"]) && $_GET["campaigns"] != null) {
$teststart = true;
$campaign_array = explode(',',$_GET["campaigns"]);
```

If I type the campaign Id and then submit the button:
the URL submitted remains:

```
http://localhost/Optimization/insight.php?campaigns=
```

However, if I copy and paste the campaign ID in the text box, the URL string becomes:

```
http://localhost/Optimization/insight.php?campaigns=70067553
```

Comment: why your action="" is blank. if it is blank it means it will submit to itself not on other page. And in your code I am seeing two pages: analysis.php, insight.php

Comment: sorry, was a typo..changed the URL

Comment: can you check the behaviour after adding one more text box, with blank value like <input type="text" name="justTest" id="Anothercampaigns">?

Comment: please provide the test inputs. and one more question where is the $campaigns declared in your php code?

Comment: what do you mean by test inputs, sorry can you please elaborate. I declared `$campaigns` in my php `$campaigns = null;`

Comment: @Rahul, the behavior is still same

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your script ::

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET["campaigns"]))
{
   $campaigns = $_GET["campaigns"];
   echo "Input field exists";
}

?>

<form method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="campaigns" value="<?php echo isset($campaigns)?$campaigns:''; ?>">
    <input type='submit' name="Submit" value="Submit" class='btn btn-success' id='idsub'>
</form>
```

You need to echo to pass php variable to html

Comment: still same behavior.. don't know why it works when I copy paste the data or hit enter in the textbox